# What does GEORGIUS III·D:G·BRITANNIARUM REX·FIDEI DEF·& c·mean?

Tags: britain, latin-language, numismatics

I recently came across this medal created to commemorate the preservation of George III from an assassination attempt in 1800:
[image: George III medal]
(the image was taken by me)

The inscription reads

```
GEORGIUS III·D:G·BRITANNIARUM REX·FIDEI DEF·& c·
```

I understand most of the inscription but cannot figure out what the "& c·" at the end means.

---

The translation that I have come up with so far is:

```
George III, by the Grace of God, King of Britain, Defender of the Faith, & ________
```

Comment: [&c](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%26c.) is usually an abbreviation of etc.

Comment: "& c." is an abbreviation for *et cetera*. I don't know what it corresponds to, however, since ([to the best of my limited knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidei_defensor)) Fidei Defensor isn't usually followed with anything.

Comment: European rulers often had a long list of historically accumulated titles, so *et cetera* stands for other, lesser titles. Examples are given on [this website](http://eurulers.altervista.org/gbritain.html), e.g. *Georgius Tertius, Dei Gratia, Magnae Britaniae, Franciae et Hiberniae, Rex, Fidei Defensor, Dux Brunsvicensis et Luneburgensis, Sacri Romani Imperil Archi-Thesaurarius et Princeps Elector etc.*

Comment: Per Wikipedia, in 1800 his full style was "George the Third, by the Grace of God, King of Great Britain, France, and Ireland, Defender of the Faith, and so forth" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_III_of_the_United_Kingdom#Titles_and_styles ), which you must admit would be pretty hard to fit on a coin.

Comment: voting to close as trivia

Comment: *Fidei Defensor* - Defender of the Faith was a title awarded to Henry VIII by Pope Leo X, for the former's defence of the Roman Catholic Church from the accusations of heresy by Martin Luther. Henry's book, written probably with considerable help from one of the English bishops, was called *the Defence of the Seven Sacraments*. Of course all this happened long before Henry applied to Rome for the annulment of his marriage. The letters FD still appear on British coins which bear the head of our present Queen. I am unclear as to whether the  papacy has ever sought to remove the title.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Elizabethan Gleanings](http://www.jstor.org/stable/548416?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), by F. W. Maitland in  The English Historical Review - Vol. 15, No. 57 (Jan., 1900), pp. 120-124,  the suffix "and so forth" (or "&c" respectively) has been first used by Queen Elizabeth I to circumnavigate the difficult question of religious affiliation (emphasis mine):

> Has this phrase (sc. "and so forth") always been meaningless ? [...]
>
> If we look at the book to which we naturally turn when we would study
>   the styles  and  titles of our English Kings, if we look at at Sir
>   Thomas Hardy's Introduction to the Charter Rolls, we shall observe
>   that the first  sovereign who bears an "&c" is Queen Elizabeth. Now
>   let us for a moment place ourselves in the first days of her reign.
>   Shall we not be eager to know what this new queen will call herself, for
>   will not her style be a presage of her policy? No doubt she is by the 
>   Grace of God of England, France and Ireland Queen. No doubt she is
>   Defender of the  Faith, though we cannot be sure what faith she will
>   defend. **But is that all ? Is she or is she not Supreme Head upon
>   earth of the Church of England and Ireland** ?
>
> The full difficulty of the question which this young lady had to face
>   as soon as she was safely queen may not be justly appreciated by our
>   modern minds.

"Styles" here refers to the "[manner of address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_(manner_of_address))". Note that the above is speculation by the author of the essay, not necessarily fact.

The trivia given as the reason for the close votes is the [claim in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera) that

> "European monarchs, who sometimes have lengthy titles due to dynastic
>   claims to territories accumulated over the centuries (and also as a
>   matter of prestige), often shorten their full titles by concluding it
>   with "et cetera"

The claim is not referenced (unless you count it as a reference that Yul Brynner in a movie based his usage of the phrase on a novel that features the king of Siam, which as a reference is absurd on a number of levels).